# Ajax Function Exit?

Tags: php

Why do people write 'exit' after the ajax function calls end

```
function ajaxValidate($params)
{
  // echo something
  exit;
}
```

When the function blocks end the code executions stops at server side so why break the code manually ?

Comment: it depends on how you have implemented the code. As for example if you are using wordpress's ajax, if you don't exit, the code will return an extra 0.

Comment: well in php i havent noticed such thing but +1 for telling me about wordpress :)

Comment: you'll also see lots of `exit(json_encode($array_of_data))`, that's because you want to make sure your output doesn't contain anything else but the response you expect to get on the client side.

Comment: Who is "people"? Haven't seen this kind of madness yet.

Answer (score 2):

The function will be called via the server-side framework, be it Joomla, Yii or anything else. So after the function returns, the framework continues to run to completion. In a cleanly designed framework, exit statement is not required as you rightly point out.

If the programmer does not understand the framework well and wants to play it safe, or has seen redundant exit values appearing the output, he/she may add the exit statement.

Comment: nyc answere but i would like to add yii its self uses Yii::app()->end(); in ajax validation but this doesnt mean they dont know anything about their framework.

For me the core reason behind using exit is still unclear

Comment: Excellent. Yii is a good framework to use. Thanks for pointing out.